# Sphere inversion in Riesz potential

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, potential-theory

I am reading the paper: ``ON THE DISTRIBUTION OF FIRST HITS FOR THE SYMMETRIC STABLE PROCESSES" by Blumenthal, Getoor and Ray, (Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 99 (1961), 540-554).

On page 546, the authors talk about the idea of Riesz regarding spherical inversions. In particular they say, for the sphere $\{u:|x-u| =r\}$, inversion is the change of coordinates
$$
u \mapsto v = x+r^2\frac{(u-x)}{|u-x|^2}.
$$ 
Then the authors explain
``Riesz noted that if $f(u)$ is a potential of exponent $\alpha$ in $R^N$, then after inversion in a sphere with center $x$, $(x —v)^{\alpha-N}f(v)$ is a potential."

I dont understand this sentence. Also later they use this idea to write some identities which I do not understand at all. For example, in page 547, they write ``if $|y| >1$, inverting along the sphere $\{u: |y-u|^2 = |y|^2-1\}$ yields
$$
\int _{|u| \le 1} (1-|u^2|)^{-\alpha/2} |u-y|^{\alpha-N}du = (|y|^2 -1)^{\alpha/2} \int_{|v| \le 1} (1-|v|^2)^{-\alpha/2} |v-y|^{-N}dv "
$$

I would be obliged if anyone can shed some light on these mysterious identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you may like to have a look at the original M. Riesz's 1938 paper: it is a *fantastic* read!

---

In the language of these papers, a "potential" of exponent $\alpha$ is a function $f$ of the form
$$ f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |y - x|^{\alpha - N} \mu(dy) , $$
where $\mu$ is a non-negative measure. M. Riesz observed that if $f$ is a potential, then its *Kelvin transform*
$$ \mathcal{K} f(x) = |x|^{\alpha - N} u(x / |x|^2) $$
is again a potential. This corresponds to inversion in the unit sphere $B(0, 1)$, that is, the change of coordinates:
$$ x \mapsto y = x / |x|^2 . $$

Obviously, the above observation extends (by translation and change of scale) to arbitrary spheres, and this is precisely the result that Blumenthal, Getoor and Ray refer to.

---

The above observation is particularly useful when inversion in the corresponding sphere preserves the unit ball. Such a sphere have a form given in the second part of your question, and the identity you are asking about is proved by the corresponding change of variable.

---

All authors mentioned above (M. Riesz, Blumenthal, Getoor and Ray) used these kind of calculations *a lot*, and rarely provided details. I believe, mostly because these are direct extensions of the well-studied case corresponding to $\alpha = 2$.

I do not know good references which give all details. A book by Bliedtner and Hansen, and perhaps a book by Landkoff, have them, if I remember correctly, but I find them both rather unfriendly.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! I have now checked the computation for N=1 and the identity is clearer now. Unfortunately, the paper by Riesz is written in French which makes it inaccessible to me. If you happen to know of any English translation, it would help me a lot. Thanks again!